# yui css compiler - accept input from php file

Tags: php, compression, yui

I'm trying to pipe all the content from a PHP generated file to [YUI CSS compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/#using).

```
// this command works great for Google Closure Javascript Compiler
php jscompressor.php | java -jar compiler.jar --js_output_file compressed.js
```

`php jscompressor.php` pulls up a PHP file that has a lot of generated JS.

**I was hopping I could do exactly this but with YUI.**
I cant.

```
// can anyone help me on this one? the following code doesnt work
php csscompressor.php | java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar -type css -o cssyui_compiled.js
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a typo on the `type`. Now works as expected.

```
// the following command pipes all output from csscompressor
// into YUI for CSS compression
php csscompressor.php | java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar -o cssyui_compiled.js --type css
```

Hope it may help someone! ;)